# How to enforce null safety annotation checks in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Consider this example:

```kotlin
import java.math.BigDecimal

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val s: String? = null
  BigDecimal(s)
}
```

it compiles without any warnings (with cli `kotlinc` and IntelliJ) and throws at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:809)
    ...
```

I tried to build it in different ways according to [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) like so:

```
kotlinc \
 -Xnullability-annotations=@javax.annotation:strict \
 -Xnullability-annotations=@org.jetbrains.annotations:strict \
 -Xjsr305=strict \
Main.kt -d main.jar
```

Annotation seems to be there (as seen in IntelliJ):

[image: @NotNull annotation in BigDecimal constructor]

Docs clearly states that:

> Java types that have nullability annotations are represented not as
> platform types, but as actual nullable or non-null Kotlin types.

What am I missing here?

Comment: BigDecimal is expecting a non-nullable type which is a String. You provide it with a an optional (nullable type) String?. So you assign null to a nullable constant s and then pass essentially null to a function that expects a non-null value.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious to the naked eye, the question here is: why there is no type mismatch: String? vs String error

Answer (score 5):

The argument to the `BigDecimal` constructor is treated as a platform type because the constructor is not actually annotated.

The `@NotNull` annotation is calculated on-the-fly by the IDE by examining the source code. If you ctrl+click on the constructor, you will go to the source code where you will see there is no annotation.

Comment: Thanks! Can I enable it somehow? I mean why IDE is calculating this on-the-fly just to ignore it without any info/warning?

Comment: It would be useful to have an inspection such as "this call may lead to null pointer exception" but I don't think there is one.

Comment: The proper solution would be to introduce something like `index.d.ts` in TypeScript, so `kotlinc` could use it and fail the build if there are extra annotations for JVM "platform" methods used incorrectly (like in this topic). Everyone could extend any the Java library to be null-safe in Kotlin.